# WebView like in Tweetro

Tags: webview, windows-8, windows-runtime

I would like to create an effect like the one that is available in Tweetro. In this program, when I show the timeline and select a tweet that contains an URL, a portion of a WebView appears on the right. When I click on it, the WebView extends on the left and becomes navigable. Then, if I click out of the WebView area, it returns on the right.

How is it possible to achieve this effect in a Windows Store App with C#?

Comment: You can have a popup control with WebView control to navigate to the link in selected tweet. Then handle events of your GridView and popup control to change position of the popup.

Comment: And what about using a WebViewBrush?

Comment: That would be a good option if you want to work with overlays on top of WebView

Answer (score 0):

Can you not host the webview and all other controls inside a grid and then change the width of the grid column/web-view as required? You can use animation to smooth out the change to give a slide effect.